# How do I get line numbers in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: user-interface, plsqldeveloper

In Preferences | User Interface | Editor | Other, I checked Display Line Numbers and set Interval to All.  However, I still have no line numbers in my text editor window.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is a second preference you need to set to get line numbers: Preferences | Window Types | SQL Window | Show gutter (line numbers).

Answer (score 8):

Right click in the area where you would expect line numbers, and select `Toggle Line Numbers`

Comment: I don't see any such menu option when right-clicking the gutter, in PL/SQL Developer 10.0.5.1710.

Answer (score 3):

preferences--user interface--"show line number" then
Right click the area of sql window and select "gutter" ,done!

Answer (score 2):

here's how to do it under pl/sql developper v12

[image: pl/sql developper v12]